# PyCharm is not producing the expected output from the current file

Tags: python, pycharm

- Whatever is added after the `while-loop` in the current script, doesn't show up as output when the script is run.

  - There is output, just not the correct output, given the current script
  - There are no errors
- Given the following script:

```py
current_total_weight = 0
first_book_list = []
books_all_weights = []
current_book_weight = []


while current_total_weight < 15:

    book_name = str(input("Enter your book's name:\n"))
    first_book_list.append(book_name)

    current_book_weight = float(input("Enter your books weight: \n"))
    books_all_weights.append(float(current_book_weight))
    current_total_weight += current_book_weight

    if current_total_weight >= 15:
        break

print("your current total of weight is", current_total_weight, "kg you still have", (15 - current_total_weight),
      "kgs worth of books")

print("you have exceeded your limit by", current_total_weight - 15)
```

- This is the output produced with `Shift + F10`, which is **RUN**.

[image: output]

- This is a view of the script and output in the PyCharm workspace

[image: full screen view with output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Each time a file is run, PyCharm saves a configuration, as shown in the following image.

[image]

- When the run button or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> are used, the current configuration is run, not necessarily the current file shown in the window.
- To resolve the issue, right click the python file you want to run, and run it from the menu, which is also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>

  - This will create and set a new current configuration, for the desired file.

[image]